# Button / Syntax Error Excel

Tags: excel, button, vba

I have a document where I want to create a button on Sheet 1 called Escelations and when pressed all data will be sent to Sheet 2 called Albany, I found some code that made kind of sense to me and I edited it to what I wanted, but when I use it and attach it to a button I get a syntax error. It is saying something is wrong with the refTable, here is the code I have:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim refTable As Variant, trans As Variant
refTable = Array("A=A15","B=E15","C=G15","D=I15","F=L15","E=AA15)
Dim Row As Long
Row = Worksheets("Albany").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
For Each trans In refTable
    Dim Dest As String, Field As String
    Dest = Trim(Left(trans, InStr(1, trans, "=") - 1)) & Row
    Field = Trim(Right(trans, Len(trans) - InStr(1, trans, "=")))
    Worksheets("Albany").Range(Dest).Value = Worksheets("Escelations").Range(Field).Value
Next
End Sub
```

---

A couple other things that I want to mention that I don't know if are causing issues but A15 is a merged cel from ABCD15/16, and the E15 is Merged, G15 is merged, I15 is merged, L15 is merged and AA15 is merged as well but where they are going to, A, B, C, D, E, F are not. Could this be an issue? Any help would be appreciated, thank you. This is my fi9rst post so if I am missing any information please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You can improve your question. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help other in the future. Fix spelling error, format code for readability, break up text into sentences and add more paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing `"`:

`refTable = Array("A=A15","B=E15","C=G15","D=I15","F=L15","E=AA15")`

Comment: Oh holy hand grenades Batman.... I feel dumb... Thank you so much, did that and it worked!

Comment: @RyanLake haha, it happens to the best of us.